# How can we stipulate not to install/configure Application Center when installing MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: installation, ibm-mobilefirst

When installing MobileFirst Platform 7.0 interactively (with a GUI), one can normally deselect the option to install & configure the Application Center automatically. However, there appears to be [no documented way](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/r_silent_installation_parameters.html) to do this when installing silently using a response file. What key/value(s) do we need to set in the response file to *not* install the Application Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MobileFirst Platform 7.0 documentation provides a set of silent installation scripts that let you install MobileFirst Platform Server with or without configuring Application center

"Working with sample response files for IBM Installation Manager" 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_silent_installation_working_with_sample_response_files.html?lang=en

It is said on this page that you should use script `install-no-appcenter.xml`
for an installation that does not install Application Center on an application server. You will find there an hyperlink that will allow you to download the archive `Silent_Install_Sample_Files.zip` that contains this `install-no-appcenter.xml` file for v7.0.